# Reading each value from a file below and extracting each value

Tags: bash, awk

Following are the contents of the file "input"

```
125.125.125.125 abcde abcde.com #comments

126.126.126.126 efg efg.com #comments
```

Output expected is

```
    <tr>
    <td> 125.125.125.125 </td>
    <td> abcde </td>
    <td> abcde.com </td>
    <td> comments </td>
    </tr>
```

Below is the script I have written

```
   for line in input
    do
            f1=$(echo $line |awk '{print $1}')
            f2=$(echo $line |awk '{print $2}')
            f3=$(echo $line |awk '{print $3}')
            f4=$(echo $line |awk -F# '{print $2}')
            echo '<tr>'
            echo '<td>'$f1'</td>'
            echo '<td>'$f2'</td>'
            echo '<td>'$f3'</td>'
            echo '<td>'$f4'</td>'
            echo '</tr>'
    done
```

Any suggestions on efficient code ?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using awk to extract each field, just use it to do the whole thing:

```
$ awk -F' +#?' 'NF{print "<tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)printf "<td>%s</td>\n",$i;print "</tr>"}' file
<tr>
<td>125.125.125.125</td>
<td>abcde</td>
<td>abcde.com</td>
<td>comments</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>126.126.126.126</td>
<td>efg</td>
<td>efg.com</td>
<td>comments</td>
</tr>
```

The `NF` condition ensures that there is no output when the line is blank (i.e. `NF` is 0). For every other line, loop through the fields, printing each one inside a `<td>...</td>`, with a `<tr>...</tr>` around the whole thing.

The field separator is one or more spaces, followed by an optional `#`, so the leading `#` before the comments is treated as part of the field separator and is removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`:

```
echo '125.125.125.125 abcde abcde.com #comments' \
| sed -re 's=(.*) (.*) (.*) #(.*)=<tr>\n<td> \1 </td>\n<td> \2 </td>\n<td> \3 </td>\n<td> \4 </td>\n</tr>='
```

or Perl:

```
echo '125.125.125.125 abcde abcde.com #comments' \
| perl -lane '$F[3] =~ s/^#//;
              print "<tr>\n<td> ",
              join(" </td>\n<td> ", @F),
              " </td>\n</tr>"'
```